# .htaccess works fine for one domain, but does not work for another. Both are on the same server

Tags: php, .htaccess

**Sorted Now. Problem was to do with the server blacklisting certain requests from running because of key phrases in the inputted text. If your having problems check that.**

I'm working on a system and have it running on two different domains on the same server. The code below works perfectly for one domain, but when I do a post request from "admin/index.php" for "admin/do/content.php", it fails miserably on the second domain. "admin/" is a real directory in both, and I have checked that the file does exist.
The .htaccess redirect code I am using is listed below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?type=$1&page=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?type=&page=$1 [L]
```

I've tried fixing it on the second domain. This is one of the many .htaccess files I've tried. It doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?type=$1&page=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?type=&page=$1 [L]
```

Really strange thing I have noticed is that refreshing the page when I get to "admin/do/content.php" on the second domain loads the page it should, but without posting the data.

EDIT [2012-06-16]: it looks like the problem may be with the script I'm calling OR the database I'm using. I'm giving it another go and will post updates later

EDIT [2012-06-20]: Wasn't the amount of data being posted. Server was throwing an Error 500 because of the string I was using. Key phrase "update * from *".

Comment: Is htaccess enabled (`AllowOverride All`) on the other domain? What are the paths to the two document_roots.

Comment: Path for the the working domain is "public_html/" and is rewritten  to "public_html/domain.com/www"before the second htaccess file.
Path for the non working domain is "public_html/domain2.com/www".

The rewrites work for the domains, it is only when I go into the admin subdir that I have noticed them going awry.

Comment: So the htaccess is inside the /admin folder (on both domains)?

Comment: htacccess is in the root of both domains.

Comment: If you rewrite the other domain instead of setting DocumentRoot in an different VirtualHost, you should use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain2.com/www/admin/` and `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ ?type=$1&page=$2 [L]`

Comment: I'm trying to avoid rewriting the other domain. I've been looking into it further, and the error I'm getting an error 500.

Comment: Looks like it might be an error with the script I'm using or the database. Will post updates later.

Comment: I have a feeling it might have something to do with the amount of data being posted. Checking it out now.

Comment: Wasn't the amount of data being posted. Server was throwing an Error 500 because of the string I was using. Key phrase "update * from *".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorted Now. Problem was to do with the server blacklisting certain requests from running because of key phrases in the inputted text. If your having problems check that.